# Why doesn't pgrep find my process if I supply too long a search term?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, grep

Can anyone explain why my `pgrep` command finds a result initially, but then gets confused if I give it too much of a search term?

```
james@jheather:~$ pgrep -a gnome-keyr
2652 /usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon --daemonize --login
james@jheather:~$ pgrep -a gnome-keyri
2652 /usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon --daemonize --login
james@jheather:~$ pgrep -a gnome-keyrin
2652 /usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon --daemonize --login
james@jheather:~$ pgrep -a gnome-keyring
2652 /usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon --daemonize --login
james@jheather:~$ pgrep -a gnome-keyring-
2652 /usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon --daemonize --login
james@jheather:~$ pgrep -a gnome-keyring-d
2652 /usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon --daemonize --login
james@jheather:~$ pgrep -a gnome-keyring-da
james@jheather:~$ pgrep -a gnome-keyring-dae
james@jheather:~$ pgrep -a gnome-keyring-daem
james@jheather:~$ pgrep -a gnome-keyring-daemo
james@jheather:~$ pgrep -a gnome-keyring-daemon
james@jheather:~$
```

This is on Ubuntu 16.04, and `pgrep` reports its version as `pgrep from procps-ng 3.3.10`.

Comment: You might find this helpful - http://askubuntu.com/questions/157075/why-does-ps-aux-grep-x-give-better-results-than-pgrep-x

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it is a duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/157075/why-does-ps-aux-grep-x-give-better-results-than-pgrep-x

Comment: @SilentMonk since it is not possible to duplicate a question from another SE site, you may want to post an answer quoting the link you mention in your comment.

Comment: @fedorqui, I have answered it. Please provide any comments if necessary.

Comment: @fedorqui: but it could be closed as relevant for another SE site...

Comment: @SergeBallesta it's relevant for both. And as it turns out, it's more applicable here than on Ask Ubuntu because it's not Ubuntu-specific.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Why does “ps aux | grep x” give better results than “pgrep x”?](https://askubuntu.com/a/157078/) in [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/):

> pgrep only looks at the first 15 characters of the executable's names.

Also if you see the man page, you can override this by providing the `-f` flag. Quoting [`man pgrep`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pgrep):

> The process name used for matching is limited to the 15 characters
>   present in the output of /proc/pid/stat. Use the -f option to match
>   against the complete command line, /proc/pid/cmdline.

Comment: Crazy crazy! Thanks!